# Data sent through AJAX not available in $_POST

Tags: php, ajax, post

My Javascript code is the following:

```
function on(logged_user) {
    alert(logged_user);

    $.ajax({
        url: "update_stats.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: logged_user
    });
}
```

update_stats.php contains

```
<?php
     $logged_user = $_POST["logged_user"];
?>
```

but I can see that $logged_user is just an empty string (I'm inserting it into a database table)

Comment: It's `data: {logged_user: logged_user}`

Answer (score 1):

Your data parameter for the `$.ajax` call is not in the right format. From the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1',
>   key2: 'value2'}

You should change that line to:

```
data: { logged_user : logged_user },
```

or

```
data: 'logged_user=' + logged_user,
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not javascript , its a jquery ajax, so please include a jquery library.
and change your function like this

**Syntax to pass the values like,**

> data: '{ "key":' + value+ ', "key":"value" }',

or

> data = "key=" + value

or

> data: JSON.stringify({ key: value, key: value}),

```
 function on(logged_user) {

        var dataString = "logged_user=" + logged_user

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_stats.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                    alert(result)
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this:

```
function on(logged_user) {
alert(logged_user);

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST', 
    url  : update_stats.php,
    data : logged_user,
    dataType : 'json', 
    encode : true
});
}
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does you code solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data in key - value format to get accesible by $_POST, $_GET and $_REQUEST  array variables in php.

```
data: {'logged_user' : data: logged_user}
```

You can access raw input like JSON data or text data which not in the key value format you can use file_get_contents("php://input") to access data.